# Regex issue in rewriter config

Tags: .net, regex, url-rewriting

I'm having an issue with bad requests from certain search parameters.

An example URL:

http://www.foo.com/washington/forums/search/%26

Results in a bad request.

The rewriter config line looks like this:

```
<rewrite url="^(.*)/forums/search/(.*)" to="~/Pages/Forums/Overview.aspx?Address=$1&amp;q=$2" processing="stop" />
```

I'm thinking it's an issue with the Regex...?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue and solution discussed here:

http://dirk.net/2008/06/09/ampersand-the-request-url-in-iis7/

Answer (score 0):

`%26` is url-encoded `&`

So the query string of the rewritten URL becomes `Address=www.foo.com/washington&q=&` which is not well-formatted due to the trailing `&`

I think you'll have to encode the string before passing to the url-rewriter

Comment: At the moment, the problem is if someone searches for &, it goes through the url encoder and gets passed to the url-rewriter as %26. This is what results in a 'bad request'.
Sorry if I'm not explaining this well!